# Update file in DB, React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using CouchDB/PouchDB to update a document in the database.

```
    this.state = {
      FirstName: "",
      LastName: "",
      DateOfBirth: "",
      City: ""
    };
  }

//.....

    global.utente.db
      .localdb()
      .find({
        selector: params
      })
      .then(response => {
        let utente = response.docs[0];
        utente.Person.FirstName = this.state.firstName;
        utente.Person.City = this.state.city;

        //.....
  render() {
     console.log(this.state.firstName)
     console.log(this.state.city)
    return (
      <View style={style.container}>
        <View style={style.page}>
          <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
          <View style={style.inputContainer}>
              <TextInput
                style={style.inputs}
                placeholder="Nome"
                placeholderTextColor="#64c7c0"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                underlineColorAndroid="grey"
                onChangeText={FirstName => this.setState({ firstName: FirstName })}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={style.inputContainer}>
              <TextInput
                style={style.inputs}
                placeholder="Citta"
                placeholderTextColor="#64c7c0"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                underlineColorAndroid="grey"
                onChangeText={City => this.setState({ city: City })}
              />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
              onPress={() => this.findUtente(this.props.cf)}
            >
              <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Modifica</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
```

I Don't understand how I can pass the value from the form. 
Because when I print the console.log(FirstName) it is empty.

I Have tried to print the response and it's right, the problem in my opinion is how I pass the value.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use state variables when updating text, so changing the onChangeText to:

```
onChangeText={FirstName => this.setState({ firstName:FirstName })}
```

After that yuo need to change also the way you define the variable after response:

```
utente.Person.FirstName = this.state.firstName;
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for reply, I don't understand your first part of the comment, it is not equal to the mine?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just edited it, see if it helps you!

Comment: What's happening?

Comment: I thought it would change the couch document instead it doesn't change it (manually passing the value or passing the value the document is updated) Instead with the form it doesn't work. Now edit the post and I'll show you everything.